# Range query on subject field

Tags: search, managed-property

I have a sharepoint site which has indexed a group of PDF documents containing metadata.  Because the PDF IFilter ignores custom metadata properties, I've thrown this metadata in the Author and Subject properties and SharePoint indexes the properties.

I can query for an exact match through my mapped properties and I get results as expected.  However, one of the properties is really a date and if I use less than or greater than operators in the query (Keyword Query Syntax or SQL), I get 0 results returned.

The field in question is mapped to docsubject AND my custom MeetingDate managed properties.
Both have the option "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison" disabled.

Is there something specific that must be done to enable range queries?